# update dictionary value in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary, swift3

```
{
  "error": false,
  "error_msg": "Get trending data.",
  "Total_category": 2,
  "responseData": [
    {
      "categoryName": "Trending",
      "Trending": [
        {
          "category": "Trending",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourit": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Comedy",
      "Comedy": [
        {
          "category": "Comedy",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourit": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```

I need for updating the content for specific key `**("isFavourit")**`, How can possible in swift 3? Update only `responseData-> index[1]->comedy[]-> "isFavourit" null to 1`.

I can set the values of the dictionary like this
`responseData[1][Comedy]![0]["isFavourit"] = 1` not working in swift3.

How can set "isFavourit" value 1?

I just tried something like

```
(arrVideoDetail[1]["comedy"] as! [Dictionary<String,Any>])[0]["isFavourit"] = 1
```

Above code show error cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Any?

Comment: Please show some code what have you tried?

Comment: Did you try searching Stack Overflow? You can't find anything about managing JSON data of this sort?

Comment: Consider to map the categories to custom objects (struct or class) and a name `isFavourit` implies to be `Bool` rather than `Int`.

Comment: share what you have tried and what errors are you getting.

Comment: @user1000 please check code

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad JSON. The problem is that the dictionaries in the `responseData` array do not have consistent keys. The first has keys

```
  "categoryName": "Trending",
  "Trending": [
```

But the second has keys

```
  "categoryName": "Comedy",
  "Comedy": [
```

This means that you don't know the name of the second key until you've pulled out the value of the `categoryName` key. So you'll have to stop and do that before you can proceed.

So, let's suppose you have your JSON in a string called `json`. Then:

```
    let d1 = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    let a1 = (d1 as! [String:Any])["responseData"]
    let d2 = (a1 as! [[String:Any]])[1]
    let key = d2["categoryName"] as! String // "Comedy"
    let a2 = d2[key]!
    var d3 = (a2 as! [[String:Any]])[0]
    // ["isWatchlist": <null>, "trailerPrice": , "isFavourit": <null>, "category": Comedy]
```

Now `d3` is the inner dictionary you are looking for and you can modify it as desired.

---

By the way, this your JSON is a nice example of why this is all going to be so much nicer in Swift 4. We can parse the whole JSON into the properties of a custom struct:

```
struct MyJson : Decodable {
    let error : Bool
    let error_msg : String
    let Total_category : Int
    let responseData : [ResponseData]
    struct ResponseData : Codable {
        let categoryName : String
        let unknown : [Inner]
        struct Inner : Codable {
            let category : String
            let trailerPrice : String
            let isFavourit : String?
            let isWatchList : String?
        }
        private struct CK : CodingKey {
            var stringValue: String
            init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
            var intValue: Int?
            init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
            self.categoryName = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey:CK(stringValue:"categoryName")!)
            let key = self.categoryName
            self.unknown = try! con.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CK(stringValue:key)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Having configured our struct, parsing the entire JSON is just one line of code! Assume your JSON is in a variable called `json`:

```
let myjson = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyJson.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

And the value you are trying to access is expressible very simply:

```
let fav = myjson.responseData[1].unknown[0].isFavourit
```

So all I have to do is make all my `let` into `var` and now they are all settable, as you trying to do.

(For more about this solution, see [Swift 4 Decodable with keys not known until decoding time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time).)