# Swift 4 Decodable with keys not known until decoding time

Tags: json, swift, decodable

How does the Swift 4 Decodable protocol cope with a dictionary containing a key whose name is not known until runtime? For example:

```
  [
    {
      "categoryName": "Trending",
      "Trending": [
        {
          "category": "Trending",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourit": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Comedy",
      "Comedy": [
        {
          "category": "Comedy",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourit": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here we have an array of dictionaries; the first has keys `categoryName` and `Trending`, while the second has keys `categoryName` and `Comedy`. The value of the `categoryName` key tells me the name of the second key. How do I express that using Decodable?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The key is in how you define the `CodingKeys` property. While it's most commonly an `enum` it can be anything that conforms to the `CodingKey` protocol. And to make dynamic keys, you can call a static function:

```
struct Category: Decodable {
    struct Detail: Decodable {
        var category: String
        var trailerPrice: String
        var isFavorite: Bool?
        var isWatchlist: Bool?
    }

    var name: String
    var detail: Detail

    private struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String

        init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }

        static let name = CodingKeys.make(key: "categoryName")
        static func make(key: String) -> CodingKeys {
            return CodingKeys(stringValue: key)!
        }
    }

    init(from coder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try coder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.detail = try container.decode([Detail].self, forKey: .make(key: name)).first!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = """
  [
    {
      "categoryName": "Trending",
      "Trending": [
        {
          "category": "Trending",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourite": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Comedy",
      "Comedy": [
        {
          "category": "Comedy",
          "trailerPrice": "",
          "isFavourite": null,
          "isWatchlist": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let categories = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Category].self, from: jsonData)
```

(I changed `isFavourit` in the JSON to `isFavourite` since I thought it was a mispelling. It's easy enough to adapt the code if that's not the case)

Comment: While you were answering, I came up with a very similar solution; I'll post it in a moment and you can see what you think.

Comment: Yours is better, obviously, but I'm glad that I independently thought of _something_. Took me all day!

Comment: Is this applicable to my situation where the dynamic keys are actually never known? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726415/using-codable-on-a-dynamic-type-object?noredirect=1#comment80406088_46726415

Comment: Anyone have any links to posts that talk about dynamic types? The key name is known and data will always be there but it could be a string or an Int.

Comment: @Martheli post a new question with the details of your problem and someone will look at it. You won't get any answer from a question in the comment

Comment: @CodeDifferent unfortunately I am unable to post questions so I am kind of stuck.

Comment: This took me a few minutes to get my head around, but it's a brilliant explanation. Thank you! Saved my poor skull from being smashed off my desk again and again! :D

Comment: This answer is pretty brilliant. Doing anything other than a defined enum never occurred to me.

Comment: What if some key of Detail are missing(i don't mean nil, but literally not included in the  in the json response) in the json response, will this be handled?

Answer (score 9):

You can write a custom struct that functions as a CodingKeys object, and initialize it with a string such that it extracts the key you specified:

```
private struct CK : CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Thus, once you know what the desired key is, you can say (in the `init(from:)` override:

```
let key = // whatever the key name turns out to be
let con2 = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
self.unknown = try! con2.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CK(stringValue:key)!)
```

So what I ended up doing is making *two* containers from the decoder — one using the standard CodingKeys enum to extract the value of the `"categoryName"` key, and another using the CK struct to extract the value of the key whose name we just learned:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.categoryName = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey:.categoryName)
    let key = self.categoryName
    let con2 = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
    self.unknown = try! con2.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CK(stringValue:key)!)
}
```

Here, then, is my entire Decodable struct:

```
struct ResponseData : Codable {
    let categoryName : String
    let unknown : [Inner]
    struct Inner : Codable {
        let category : String
        let trailerPrice : String
        let isFavourit : String?
        let isWatchList : String?
    }
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case categoryName
    }
    private struct CK : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.categoryName = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey:.categoryName)
        let key = self.categoryName
        let con2 = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
        self.unknown = try! con2.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CK(stringValue:key)!)
    }
}
```

And here's the test bed:

```
    let json = """
      [
        {
          "categoryName": "Trending",
          "Trending": [
            {
              "category": "Trending",
              "trailerPrice": "",
              "isFavourit": null,
              "isWatchlist": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "categoryName": "Comedy",
          "Comedy": [
            {
              "category": "Comedy",
              "trailerPrice": "",
              "isFavourit": null,
              "isWatchlist": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    """
    let myjson = try! JSONDecoder().decode(
        [ResponseData].self, 
        from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(myjson)
```

And here's the output of the print statement, proving that we've populated our structs correctly:

```
[JustPlaying.ResponseData(
    categoryName: "Trending", 
    unknown: [JustPlaying.ResponseData.Inner(
        category: "Trending", 
        trailerPrice: "", 
        isFavourit: nil, 
        isWatchList: nil)]), 
 JustPlaying.ResponseData(
    categoryName: "Comedy", 
    unknown: [JustPlaying.ResponseData.Inner(
        category: "Comedy", 
        trailerPrice: "", 
        isFavourit: nil, 
        isWatchList: nil)])
]
```

Of course in real life we'd have some error-handling, no doubt!

---

**EDIT** Later I realized (in part thanks to CodeDifferent's answer) that I didn't need two containers; I can eliminate the CodingKeys enum, and my CK struct can do all the work! It is a general purpose key-maker:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
    self.categoryName = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey:CK(stringValue:"categoryName")!)
    let key = self.categoryName
    self.unknown = try! con.decode([Inner].self, forKey: CK(stringValue:key)!)
}
```

Comment: We essentially came up with the same solution!

Comment: Yeah, but you win the prize. It just never occurred to me to use just the struct alone. Yet it's so obvious now. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I eventually came up for this json:

```
let json = """
{
    "BTC_BCN":{
        "last":"0.00000057",
        "percentChange":"0.03636363",
        "baseVolume":"47.08463318"
    },
    "BTC_BELA":{
        "last":"0.00001281",
        "percentChange":"0.07376362",
        "baseVolume":"5.46595029"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

We make such a structure:

```
struct Pair {
    let name: String
    let details: Details

    struct Details: Codable {
        let last, percentChange, baseVolume: String
    }
}
```

then decode:

```
if let pairsDictionary = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: Pair.Details].self, from: json) {
    
    var pairs: [Pair] = []
    for (name, details) in pairsDictionary {
        let pair = Pair(name: name, details: details)
        pairs.append(pair)
    }
    
    print(pairs)
}
```

It is also possible to call not pair.details.baseVolume, but pair.baseVolume:

```
struct Pair {
    ......
    var baseVolume: String { return details.baseVolume }
    ......
```

Or write custom init:

```
struct Pair {
    .....
    let baseVolume: String
    init(name: String, details: Details) {
         self.baseVolume = details.baseVolume
    ......
```