# Using Codable on a dynamic type/object

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

Hi I have the following structure nested in a bigger structure that is returned from an api call but I can't manage to encode/decode this part. The problem I am having is that the customKey and customValue are both dynamic.

```
{
    "current" : "a value"
    "hash" : "some value"
    "values": {
        "customkey": "customValue",
        "customKey": "customValue"
    }
}
```

I tried something like `var values: [String:String]` But that is obviously not working because its not actually an array of `[String:String]`.

Comment: @vadian I don't see how this is duplicate of any of those questions. I modified the question to be more clear now.

Comment: I understand and reopened the question: Short answer: You cannot use `Codable` with dynamic keys.

Comment: Can you recommend another way to do this?

Comment: If the keys are dynamic you can only use a dynamic collection type, in this case a dictionary.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use it with a Dictionary?

Comment: It depends on *nested in a bigger structure*. But when you deserialize the entire JSON with `JSONSerialization` you get the collection types for free.

Comment: hmm so I need to stop using Codable for this call and use JSONSerialization?

Comment: Once again, *You cannot use Codable with dynamic keys*

Comment: @vadian you can. See the answer from Code Different below :)

Comment: That's not really *dynamic keys*. You need to define the actual keys anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you linked to my answer to another question, I will expand that one to answer yours.

Truth is, all keys are known at runtime if you know where to look:

```
struct GenericCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var intValue: Int?
    var stringValue: String

    init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }

    static func makeKey(name: String) -> GenericCodingKeys {
        return GenericCodingKeys(stringValue: name)!
    }
}


struct MyModel: Decodable {
    var current: String
    var hash: String
    var values: [String: String]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case current
        case hash
        case values
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        current = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .current)
        hash = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .hash)

        values = [String: String]()
        let subContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: GenericCodingKeys.self, forKey: .values)
        for key in subContainer.allKeys {
            values[key.stringValue] = try subContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "current": "a value",
    "hash": "a value",
    "values": {
        "key1": "customValue",
        "key2": "customValue"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. How would this apply if I have others keys in the JSON next to values that are normal decodable, Do I add a normal enum container for that ?

Comment: I'm getting confused with your new requirements. Can you edit the JSON to show an example of it?

Comment: I edited the JSON. What I meant was that the actual object that I am encoding and decoding has more than only values key->object. :)

Comment: @CodeDifferent I'm in a similar situation but in my case, i know "key1" and "key2" but not "values", i didn't figure out how to adapt your code, could you help ? thanks !

Comment: @TmSmth there’s not enough info for me to help here. Please post a new question with the details of your specific situation

Comment: @CodeDifferent here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308859/dynamic-dictionary-name-decoder-json

Answer (score 1):

Simplified answer, it is working with dictionary [String: String] (instatead of String you can use other struct):

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "current": "a value",
    "hash": "a value",
    "values": {
        "key1": "customValue",
        "key2": "customValue"
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct MyModel: Decodable {
    var current: String
    var hash: String
    var values: [String: String]
}

let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: jsonData)

for (key,value) in model.values {
    print("key: \(key) value: \(value)")
}
```