# dynamic dictionary name decoder json

Tags: json, swift, swift4

Swift 4. I'm in a very similar situation than [Using Codable on a dynamic type/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726415/using-codable-on-a-dynamic-type-object) but for me the changing variable is the name of the dictionary and not the keys inside. It looks like :

```
{
    "customName": {
        "constantKey": Double,
        "constantKey2": Double,
    }
}
```

Here is the code i'm trying to change, it has been proposed as the answer for the other question and i did little changes :

```
 struct GenericCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var intValue: Int?
    var stringValue: String

    init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }

    static func makeKey(name: String) -> GenericCodingKeys {
        return GenericCodingKeys(stringValue: name)!
    }
}


struct MyModel: Decodable {
    var customName: [String: Double]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case customName
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    customName = [String: String]()
    let subContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: GenericCodingKeys.self, forKey: .customName)
    for key in subContainer.allKeys {
        customName[key.stringValue] = try subContainer.decode(Double.self, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the obvious error i got as i don't know how to change this custom name : `keyNotFound(Testapp.MyModel.(CodingKeys in _7A951077E4B6EF2E56D367C5DE0BF0AC).customName, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Cannot get KeyedDecodingContainer<GenericCodingKeys> -- no value found for key \"customName\"", underlyingError: nil))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know all the keys in the inner JSON, use a struct to take advantage of static typing. Assuming that there's only 1 key on the top level in your JSON (your `customName` key):

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    struct InnerModel: Decodable {
        var constantKey1: Double
        var constantKey2: Double
    }

    var customName: InnerModel

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: GenericCodingKeys.self)

        // Assume that there's only 1 key at the top level in the JSON
        if let key = container.allKeys.first {
            customName = try container.decode(InnerModel.self, forKey: key)
        } else {
            throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "JSON is empty"])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! I don't know exactly how as it still looks like kind of black magic for me, but I'll study this !