# Nested JSON with dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, codable

I've got stuck on parsing JSON with dynamic keys.
JSON looks like:

```
{
   "customName": {
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double,
        "customKey": Double
   }
}
```

The only thing that is known - the number of customKeys inside each customName - 7

I need a Dictionary of ["customKey": Double]

My problem is very similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308859/dynamic-dictionary-name-decoder-json), but I have all keys dynamic.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: DId it, just `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataToDecode, options: []) as! [String : [String:Double]]`