# Dynamic JSON Decoding Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, dynamic, decodable

I'm trying to decode the following JSON in Swift 4:

```
{
    "token":"RdJY3RuB4BuFdq8pL36w",
    "permission":"accounts, users",
    "timout_in":600,
    "issuer": "Some Corp",
    "display_name":"John Doe",
    "device_id":"uuid824fd3c3-0f69-4ee1-979a-e8ab25558421"
}
```

The problem is, the last 2 elements (`display_name` and `device_id`) in the JSON may or may not exist or the elements could be named something entirely different but still unknown, i.e `"fred": "worker", "hours" : 8`

So what I'm trying to achieve is decode what IS known, i.e `token`, `permission`, `timeout_in` and `issuer` and any other elements (`display_name`, `device_id` etc) place them into a dictionary.

My structure looks like this:

```
struct AccessInfo : Decodable
{
    let token: String
    let permission: [String]
    let timeout: Int
    let issuer: String
    let additionalData: [String: Any]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case token
        case permission
        case timeout = "timeout_in"
        case issuer
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        token = container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
        permission = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .permission).components(separatedBy: ",")
        timeout = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: . timeout)
        issuer = container.decode(String.self, forKey: .issuer)

        // This is where I'm stuck, how do I add the remaining
        // unknown JSON elements into additionalData?
    }
}

// Calling code, breviated for clarity
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let accessInfo = try decoder.decode(AccessInfo.self, from: data!)
```

Being able to decode a parts of a known structure where the JSON could contain dynamic info as well is where I'm at if anyone could provide some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Please provide _real_ JSON.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired by @matt comments, here is the full sample I've gone with.  I  extended the `KeyedDecodingContainer` to decode the unknown keys and provide a parameter to filter out known `CodingKeys`.

**Sample JSON**

```
{
    "token":"RdJY3RuB4BuFdq8pL36w",
    "permission":"accounts, users",
    "timout_in":600,
    "issuer": "Some Corp",
    "display_name":"John Doe",
    "device_id":"uuid824fd3c3-0f69-4ee1-979a-e8ab25558421"
}
```

**Swift structs**

```
struct AccessInfo : Decodable
{
    let token: String
    let permission: [String]
    let timeout: Int
    let issuer: String
    let additionalData: [String: Any]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case token
        case permission
        case timeout = "timeout_in"
        case issuer
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        token = container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
        permission = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .permission).components(separatedBy: ",")
        timeout = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: . timeout)
        issuer = container.decode(String.self, forKey: .issuer)

        // Additional data decoding
        let container2 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AdditionalDataCodingKeys.self)
        self.additionalData = container2. decodeUnknownKeyValues(exclude: CodingKeys.self)
    }
}

private struct AdditionalDataCodingKeys: CodingKey
{
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String)
    {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int)
    {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**KeyedDecodingContainer Extension**

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer where Key == AdditionalDataCodingKeys
{
    func decodeUnknownKeyValues<T: CodingKey>(exclude keyedBy: T.Type) -> [String: Any]
    {
        var data = [String: Any]()

        for key in allKeys
        {
            if keyedBy.init(stringValue: key.stringValue) == nil
            {
                if let value = try? decode(String.self, forKey: key)
                {
                    data[key.stringValue] = value
                }
                else if let value = try? decode(Bool.self, forKey: key)
                {
                    data[key.stringValue] = value
                }
                else if let value = try? decode(Int.self, forKey: key)
                {
                    data[key.stringValue] = value
                }
                else if let value = try? decode(Double.self, forKey: key)
                {
                    data[key.stringValue] = value
                }
                else if let value = try? decode(Float.self, forKey: key)
                {
                    data[key.stringValue] = value
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog("Key %@ type not supported", key.stringValue)
                }
            }
        }

        return data
    }
}
```

**Calling code**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let accessInfo = try decoder.decode(AccessInfo.self, from: data!)

print("Token: \(accessInfo.token)")
print("Permission: \(accessInfo.permission)")
print("Timeout: \(accessInfo.timeout)")
print("Issuer: \(accessInfo.issuer)")
print("Additional Data: \(accessInfo.additionalData)")
```

**Output**

```
Token: RdJY3RuB4BuFdq8pL36w
Permission: ["accounts", "users"]
Timeout: 600
Issuer: "Some Corp"
Additional Data: ["display_name":"John Doe", "device_id":"uuid824fd3c3-0f69-4ee1-979a-e8ab25558421"]
```

Comment: After hours of searching, this finally helped me! The one thing I don't understand is the following line: `if keyedBy.init(stringValue: key.stringValue) == nil`. Why does this return nil?

Answer (score 1):

The question is actually a duplicate of [Swift 4 Decodable with keys not known until decoding time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time). Once you understand the trick about building a rock-bottom minimal CodingKey adopter struct as your coding key, you can use it for any dictionary.

In this instance, you would use the keyed container's `allKeys` to get the unknown JSON dictionary keys.

To demonstrate, I will confine myself to just the completely unknown part of the JSON dictionary. Imagine this JSON:

```
let j = """
{
    "display_name":"John Doe",
    "device_id":"uuid824fd3c3-0f69-4ee1-979a-e8ab25558421"
}
"""
let jdata = j.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Presume that we have no idea what's in that dictionary, beyond that the fact that it has String keys and String values. So we want to parse `jdata` without knowing anything about what its keys are.

We therefore have a struct consisting of one dictionary property:

```
struct S {
    let stuff : [String:String]
}
```

The question now is how to parse that JSON into that struct - i.e., how to make that struct conform to Decodable and deal with that JSON.

Here's how:

```
struct S : Decodable {
    let stuff : [String:String]
    private struct CK : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: CK.self)
        var d = [String:String]()
        for key in con.allKeys {
            let value = try! con.decode(String.self, forKey:key)
            d[key.stringValue] = value
        }
        self.stuff = d
    }
}
```

Now we parse:

```
let s = try! JSONDecoder().decode(S.self, from: jdata)
```

And we get an S instance whose `stuff` is this dictionary:

```
["device_id": "uuid824fd3c3-0f69-4ee1-979a-e8ab25558421", "display_name": "John Doe"]
```

And that is the very result we wanted.

Comment: And what if the unknown data is not always of the type `[String:String]`?

Comment: That is a different issue, which has also been dealt with thoroughly here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I reviewed [swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time) and code sample by @matt works fine.  It's when combining **known keys** and **unknown keys** in a single parse/decoding operation when the implementation gets tricky, because you want to decode the container twice...  Or decode as a generic approach, and _manually_ assign the known keys dropping the remainder unknown keys into the dictionary `[String: String]`

Comment: You go in twice, once with the known keys, as you already showed, and once again diving for the unknown keys, as I did. Do I need to spell the whole thing out?

Comment: Can someone provide link of SO question regarding known keys but unknown data type?