# Using Swift 4 Codable Protocol with Unknown Dictionary Keys

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I am working with NASA's [Near Earth Object Web Service](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/?api_key=DEMO_KEY#!/rest%2Fv1%2Ffeed/retrieveNearEarthObjectFeed) to retrieve data to be displayed in an application. I understand how to use Swift 4's `Codable` protocol, but I do not understand how to map part of the response.

Using [Paw](https://paw.cloud), I inspected the response from the API:

[image: Image of API response data]

As you can see, the `near_earth_objects` structure is a `Dictionary`, and the keys are dates. The issue is that the URL parameters are dates, so these date structures will change, depending on the day of the request. Therefore, I do not know how I can create properties to be automatically mapped when using the `Codable` protocol.

The data that I am trying to get to inside of these structures are `Array`s that contain `Dictionary`s:

[image: Image of API response data]

How can I have my model object conform to the `Codable` protocol and map these structures when the dates will change as the dates of the requests change?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603630/dynamic-json-decoding-swift-4/47604459?noredirect=1#comment82179797_47604459

Comment: Can you post a json sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know the keys of the `Dictionary` compile time if you don't mind keeping a `Dictionary` after decoding.

You just need to specify the property with type `Dictionary<String:YourCustomDecodableType>`. The keys will be dates corresponding to observation and the value will an array of all objects with your custom type.

```
struct NearEarthObject: Codable {
    let referenceID:String
    let name:String
    let imageURL:URL

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case referenceID = "neo_reference_id"
        case name
        case imageURL = "nasa_jpl_url"
    }
}

struct NEOApiResponse: Codable {
    let nearEarthObjects: [String:[NearEarthObject]]

    private enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
        case nearEarthObjects = "near_earth_objects"
    }
}

do {
    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(NEOApiResponse.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `near_earth_objects` is a Dictionary, but keys are not Dates, keys are Strings, and values are arrays of the known structures. So the above code will work:

```
...
let nearEarthObjects: [String: [IndexObject]]
...

enum CodingKey: String, CodingKeys {
    case nearEarthObjects = "near_earth_objects"
}

struct IndexObject: Decodable {
    ...
    let name: String
    ...
}
```