# How to parse below dynamic JSON in swift 4.2?

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

```
{
  "payload": {
    “key1”: “value1”,
    “key2”: "{\"command\": \"playSound\",\"tone\": 0,\"delay\": 100000}”,
    “key3”: 0
  },
}
```

Above is my response data, whereas 'payload' is known key but inside 'payload' all keys & values are unknown.

e.g. 'key1' can be any name and value of 'key1' can be anything (Int/String/Dictionary).

My code is like below, but it doesn't work.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let dict = try! decoder.decode([String: Any].self, from: data!)
    complete(true, dict, nil)
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603630/dynamic-json-decoding-swift-4

Comment: @leparlon, this does not help. That question/answer has static json, which will always have the same set of keys, and 2 optional keys. This question is about unknown keys with unknown value types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to fall back to the old `JSONSerialization`, but the downside is you lose the `Decodable` support for the known keys on the top level.

Another option is to implement the `init(from: Decoder)` method of your outer object (the one that has `payload`), and manually decode the dictionary there.

Or there are `Codable`-conforming wrappers that you can use instead of `Any`. Here is [one](https://github.com/arkku/swift-arkku/blob/master/Sources/SwiftArkku/Wrappers/AValue.swift) (disclaimer: I am the author).